# understanding some assembly code

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to learn some assembly code, so I read in some tutorial that the assembly code for

```
int proc(void)
  {
      int x,y;
       scanf("%x %x", &y, &x);
       return x-y;
   }
```

is

```
1   proc:
2     pushl  %ebp
3     movl  %esp, %ebp
4     subl   $40, %esp
5     leal  -4(%ebp), %eax
6     movl  %eax, 8(%esp)
7     leal  -8(%ebp), %eax
8     movl  %eax, 4(%esp)
9     movl  $.LC0, (%esp)
10    call  scanf
 Diagram stack frame at this point
11    movl  -4(%ebp), %eax
12    subl  -8(%ebp), %eax
13    leave
14    ret
```

If I well understood, the instructions of line 5 to 8 store some addresses that will be used to store the values of `scanf`'s input. So is it right to say that `scanf` uses systematically the address `%esp` plus a certain number of bytes (depending on the `sizeof` the input) to fetch the address at which is the data will be stored ?

Comment: Compiling with debugging symbols and using objdump -S you can get the assembly code interleaved with the C code. It can help.

Comment: In my humble opinion, starting to learn assembly code by trying to understand [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) details is not the most effective way.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that a stack frame is built up to pass arguments to `scanf`. `subl` is used to allocate space for the new stack frame and the `movl` is used with offsets from the stack pointer, `%esp`, to write values for the arguments on the freshly allocated stack frame.

A more thorough explanation on x86 calling conventions and cdecl in particular can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). Understanding the high-level structure of the stack frame and the cdecl convention will help you make sense of the intent of this code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Calling convention of `scanf` is `cdecl`. It passes its arguments to stack pointed by `esp`.